# Can't figure out why my update query is not working

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

I have added an integer column `columnY` to table `tableX`, I wrote an update script which should update this column for row with specific Id value, but when I execute this script it reports that it was completed successfully (`@@ERROR = 0`), but the value is not updated

Desired results would be this update query to update column value...

Here's the query

```
Begin
update tableX
set columnY=1
where rowId=446
end 

if (@@ERROR=0)
begin       
    select columnY from tableX where rowId=446
end 

go
```

Currently this query returns `Null` value, although, to my understanding, it should (that would be the desired behaviour) return value `1`

I don't get (and for now - have had no luck finding anything about this issue on the net) what is the problem here... I tried to add some more columns, but they also got this strange behaviour - not possible to update column value but no error produced when I run update query...

Comment: I don't know SQL Server, but don't they have transactions, and therefore a COMMIT statement?

Comment: Did you check if the row with `rowId` actually exists? Execute this `select * from tableX where rowId=446` and see what it returns

Comment: @JorgeCampos the row exists, I have checked it

Comment: @Aganju it should work anyway... but I tried also with `begin transaction` ... `commit transaction` with no result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, the error is somewhere else... Maybe a Trigger in your table???

Tried this:

```
CREATE TABLE tableX(rowId INT,columnY INT);
INSERT INTO tableX VALUES(446,0);

select columnY from tableX where rowId=446

Begin
update tableX
set columnY=1
where rowId=446
end 

if (@@ERROR=0)
begin       
    select columnY from tableX where rowId=446
end 
GO

DROP TABLE tableX;
```

The result is - as expected - first 0 and then 1

Comment: Thanks a lot! :) You were right - there were a trigger with `INSTEAD OF UPDATE` - I didn't now that it was possible to override update query with a trigger. Thanks again! :)